# Read a properties file in powershell

Tags: powershell, properties-file

Let's suppose that I have a file.properties and its content is:

```
app.name=Test App
app.version=1.2
...
```

how can I get the value of app.name?

Comment: You could use a regular expression or `-split` the lines at `=`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use ConvertFrom-StringData to convert Key=Value pairs to a hash table:

```
$filedata = @'
app.name=Test App
app.version=1.2
'@

$filedata | set-content appdata.txt

$AppProps = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content ./appdata.txt -raw)
$AppProps

Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
app.version                    1.2                                                                   
app.name                       Test App                                                              

$AppProps.'app.version'

 1.2
```

Comment: thanks!!! I have implemented my code as follows:
$AppProps = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content ./app.properties -raw)

$AppProps.'client.version'

Comment: The `-Raw` flag has been added in PowerShell 3. If you want to use this on PowerShell 2 use `Get-Content $file | Out-String` instead.

Answer (score 13):

If you are running with powershell v2.0 you might be missing the "-Raw" argument for Get-Content. In this case you can use the following.

Content of C:\temp\Data.txt:

> environment=Q GRZ
>
> target_site=FSHHPU

Code:

```
$file_content = Get-Content "C:\temp\Data.txt"
$file_content = $file_content -join [Environment]::NewLine

$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData($file_content)
$environment = $configuration.'environment'
$target_site = $configuration.'target_site'
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add the solution if you need escaping (for example if you have paths with backslashes):

```bsh
$file_content = Get-Content "./app.properties" -raw
$file_content = [Regex]::Escape($file_content)
$file_content = $file_content -replace "(\\r)?\\n", [Environment]::NewLine
$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData($file_content)
$configuration.'app.name'
```

Without the -raw:

```bsh
$file_content = Get-Content "./app.properties"
$file_content = [Regex]::Escape($file_content -join "`n")
$file_content = $file_content -replace "\\n", [Environment]::NewLine
$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData($file_content)
$configuration.'app.name'
```

Or in a one-line fashion:

```bsh
(ConvertFrom-StringData([Regex]::Escape((Get-Content "./app.properties" -raw)) -replace "(\\r)?\\n", [Environment]::NewLine)).'app.name'
```

Comment: This was my exact problem! Thanks for adding this.

Comment: Why the regex escape and manually-normalized line endings? `Get-Content` seems to handle either line endings automatically on my system (Windows 10.0.17134.765).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is some Powershell integrated way of doing this, but I can do it with regex:

```
$target = "app.name=Test App
app.version=1.2
..."

$property = "app.name"
$pattern = "(?-s)(?<=$($property)=).+"

$value = $target | sls $pattern | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value}

Write-Host $value
```

Should print "Test App"