# capture data from ini file PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, ini

I would like to parse an ini file and capture data from a Section. Basically I am trying to capture the version of an AV installed on 1000+ Servers. the ini file contains "Program_Version". This variable contains the version no. If I search using Program_Version=, I directly find the phrase after the "=" sign it contains the version no. Like 8.0, 10.6 etc

Can some one please guide me on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I use :

```
function Parse-IniFile
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Alias("Fichier")]
    [string]$fic
  )

  begin {} 

  Process 
  {
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $fic 
    {
      "^\[(.+)\]$"
      {
        $section = $matches[1]
        $ini[$section] = @{}
      }
      "(.+)=(.+)" 
      {
        $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
      }
    }

    return $ini
  }

  end {}
}
```

given an INI file from "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" directory tree.

```
$p = Parse-IniFile "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\adihdaud.inf_amd64_neutral_66552f06054bc4ee\Mixer.ini"
$p["FRENCH"]["KSPINNAME_ADI_ALT_PCBEEP_SOURCE"]
```

gives

```
"Bip PC"
```

Answer (score 0):

.ini files are normally key = value pairs, that are easily convertible to a hash table using ConvertFrom-StringData

[Read a properties file in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275525/read-a-properties-file-in-powershell/20276315#20276315)

From there it's just a matter of reading the value of the hash Program_Version key from the hash table.