# Update properties file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to update below property file contents using powershell and replace ${BuildPath} with location = 
D:\Data\Sample\lib

```
tibco.alias.junit.jar=${BuildPath}\\junit.jar
tibco.alias.TextDiff.jar=${BuildPath}\\TextDiff.jar
tibco.alias.XMLDiff.jar=${BuildPath}\\XMLDiff.jar
```

Could some one please help me logic on powershell to update this property file.

Thanks

Comment: Are there more properties other than that on the file or is that it?

Comment: Matt, Above contents are in one property file(alias.properties), i just want to replace ${BuildPath} with location (D\:\\Data\\Sample\\lib)

Comment: Do you need to escape all slashes and colons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have a file with those properties in it yes? Who's to say how it was created or if that is the only contents? Lets just assume you have a file with lots of properties other than that just in case. You want to navigate the file replacing all occurrences* of `${BuildPath}` with `D:\Data\Sample\lib`

```
$replacePath = "D:\Data\Sample\lib"
$newFile = Get-Content c:\temp\file.ini | ForEach-Object{
    $_ -replace '\${BuildPath}',($replacePath -replace '\\',"\\")
} 
$newFile | Set-Content c:\temp\file.ini
```

This would give the following output in `c:\temp\file.ini`

```
tibco.alias.junit.jar=D:\\Data\\Sample\\lib\\junit.jar
tibco.alias.TextDiff.jar=D:\\Data\\Sample\\lib\\TextDiff.jar
tibco.alias.XMLDiff.jar=D:\\Data\\Sample\\lib\\XMLDiff.jar
```

* regex will only replace the first occurrence on each line. Doubt there would be more than one anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you are rewriting the entire file and you don't need to keep the comments you can use the load syntax here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276315/3794873 and then the write syntax here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210799/3794873 but mind the notes about losing ordering.

If you need to keep the original order, see the other answer using `-replace`, or create an OrderedDict in PowerShell and populate it via a loop over the lines in the file (see example in code below).

I've condensed the linked question and answer above in the example below.

```
$filename = 'myfile.properties'
$filedata = @'
app.name=Test App
app.version=1.2
app.data=Some words
'@

$filedata | set-content $filename


# This method doesn't maintain ordering
$fileProps = convertfrom-stringdata (Get-Content $filename | Out-String) 
#could use also use -raw in PS 3 or higher instead of | Out-String
Write-Output "Initial data"
$fileProps.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Write-Output
$fileProps['app.name'] = 'StringData App'
Write-Output "Updated data"
$fileProps.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Write-Output
$fileProps.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Out-File .\myfile.stringdata.properties -Encoding "ASCII"

# This method uses an ordered dict to maintain... order    
$dict = [ordered]@{}
Get-Content $filename | foreach-object {$dict.add($_.split('=',2)[0],$_.split('=',2)[1])}
Write-Output "Initial data"
$dict.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Write-Output
$dict['app.name'] = 'Ordered Dict App'
Write-Output "Updated data"
$dict.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Write-Output
$dict.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Out-File .\myfile.ordered.properties -Encoding "ASCII"
```

Comment: what if the file contains multiple comments which are equal? It complains that it can't add the key again...

Comment: I'm afraid duplicate comments would be tricky and would probably involve needing to track how many times the same comment was "seen" by reading the file line by line in a slightly different manner and appending a number to every instance after the first one before converting to a hash table.

Comment: Excellent script @dragon788. I updated the script so it preserves empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Working off @dragon788 answer, I made a version which maintains empty lines.

```
$filename = 'myfile.properties'
$filedata = @'
app.name=Test App
app.version=1.2
app.data=Some words
'@

$filedata | set-content $filename


# This method uses an ordered dict to maintain... order    
$dict = [ordered]@{}
$crlf = 0
Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $key = $_.split('=',2)[0]
    $value = $_.split('=',2)[1]

    if ($key -ne '')
    {
        $dict.add($key, $value)
    } else {
        $dict.add('crlf_' + $crlf++, '')
    }
}
Write-Output "Initial data"
$dict.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -like 'crlf_*'){
        ""
    } else {
        "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" 
    }
} | Write-Output

# Update values
$dict['database'] = 'sqlserver'

Write-Output "Updated data"
$dict.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -like 'crlf_*'){
        ""
    } else {
        "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" 
    }
} | Write-Output
$dict.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -like 'crlf_*'){
        ""
    } else {
        "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" 
    }
} | Out-File .\myfile.ordered.properties -Encoding "ASCII"
```