# How to edit a .property file in powershell

Tags: properties-file, powershell-4.0

I have a application.properties file in following format

```
application.name=some thing
application.version=4.1.0.1
application.list=abc.def, ghi.jkl
```

Now my task is to append mno.pqr to application.list
I am able to read it using

`$AppProps = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content .\application.properties -raw)`

I changed the `Application.list` value in `$AppProps`.
How to save it back to original Application.properties file..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```powershell
$AppProps.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } > .\application.properties
```

<sup>Note that `>` creates UTF-16 LE files (with BOM) by default, so if you want to control the encoding explicitly, pipe to either `Out-File` or `Set-Content` using the `-Encoding` parameter instead.</sup>

There is no complementary `ConvertTo-StringData`, unfortunately, so you have to create your own output formatting (the default output format of a hashtable does *not* work as a properties file):

- `ConvertFrom-StringData` returns a hashtable, so `$AppProps` contains one.
- `$AppProps.GetEnumerator()` sends the hashtable's key/value pairs (dictionary entries of type `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`) one by one through the pipeline.

  - The `.GetEnumerator()` call is necessary, because PowerShell treats a hashtable as a *single* object in a pipeline.
- `% { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }` constructs the output string for each key/value pair.

---

**Caveats** that stem from using  `ConvertFrom-StringData` to read properties files:

- Loss of ordering: Since key ordering is not guaranteed in a hashtable, the properties will typically appear in different order when you rewrite the file (at least the first time).
- Loss of comments: Comments in the input file (lines whose first non-blank char. is `#`) are quietly skipped on reading, so you'll lose them when you rewrite the file.